# How do I pass transient secrets, like passwords, between Rails objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, passwords

I am writing a Rails 7 application which has user accounts, and user child objects whose creation should trigger external API calls. These API calls need the clear-text password of the user, but (obviously) I don't want to save this password in the database. The structure is something like this:

```
class User
  has_many :services
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :services

  # this creates transient parameters :password and :password_confirmation to enter the cleartext password in forms, 
  # and a database field :crypted_password with a salted password hash.
  has_secure_password

  before_validation :set_defaults
  def set_defaults
    # randomly generated, then sent to the user by email as email address confirmation
    self.password = self.password_confirmation = generate_password
    # ...
  end
end

class Service
  belongs_to :user

  after_create :call_api
  def call_api
    # this does not work because user.password is not accessible, even when the user has also just been created
    ExternalApi.call('create', user_id: user.id, password: user.password, ...)
  end
end
```

Calling the external API in an after_create (or before_create) call doesn't work because the parent object's transient attributes (:password) are not accessible.

In reality my structure is a little more complex, and I am also considering using async external processes (cronjobs) to do the external API calls, instead of synchronous after_create calls, to avoid timeouts when the API is offline. That makes secure passing of passwords even more complex.

The only chance I see currently - at least when initially creating a user - is to *temporarily* actually store the password in the database in clear text, and remove it once all API calls have been successful. But I don't like that solution. Are there other options that don't require a complex additional infrastructure?

Comment: What kind of API requires you to use cleartext passwords? The whole thing sounds very dodgy. And I don't think you'll find any solution that doesn't have some pretty dire security consecuences. Password encryption is one way by design.

Comment: An API call that creates the same user, with the same password, on a remote service as the user which was just created on my web application requires passing on that password one single time. After that, I can use tokens.